# Obtaining Playframework configuration without using Guice DI

Tags: scala, playframework

Is there a way to access the application configurations without using Guice DI?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to avoid dependency injection altogether or are you looking for alternatives to guice? if so, runtime or compile time? however to answer your question in the most basic sense: yes, there is a way.

Comment: A new feature needs to be added to an existing object and this requires getting some application configurations.  If Guice DI is used to inject the configuration, not only this one object has to be turned into a class, all other objects that use it also have to be changed to a class and use DI to inject this object.  I am trying to explore other options.

Comment: Ah well if your thing is static then you'll need to either statically access the config (by means of `Play.current`) or pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks @rethab.  Play.current is deprecated.  I probably will use it until I figure out a better way.